# Find duplicates and sum quantities

Tags: python, duplicates, odoo

I am using odoo studio and in my model, there is an one2many field named x_studio_items.
Subfields are mainly x_studio_outward_item and x_studio_qty.
I want to merge the duplicate products in x_studio_outward item and sum x_studio_qty.
I am using this script to get the single value and remove duplicates

```
for rec in record.x_studio_items:
  output.add(rec.x_studio_outward_item.x_studio_item_id)
```

which is working perfectly fine.
I want a script to add all the duplicate item quantities of output.
Thanks

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it's done with a `read_group`. But the `read_group` is a database search function, so you need the relation info and table the name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you share any sample script for that?